# Totient function; if $\phi(ap)=\phi(a)\phi(p)$ and $p$ is prime, then $p\nmid a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

If p is a prime and $\phi(ap)=\phi(a)\phi(p)$ can one conclude that a and p are relatively prime? I need to show that p does not divide a, but I'm not sure if $\phi(ap)=\phi(a)\phi(p)$ is enough to show that.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, $\varphi(ap) = \varphi(a)\varphi(p)$ is enough to conclude that $a$ and $p$ are coprime. For $p$ prime, if $p$ divided $a$, we would have $\varphi(ap) = \varphi(a)\cdot p > \varphi(a)\varphi(p)$. More generally, you have

$$\varphi(n) = n\cdot \prod_{p\mid n}\left(1 - \frac1p\right),$$

and if $m$ and $n$ have a common prime factor $p$, the factor $\left( 1 - \frac1p\right)$ appears only once in $\varphi(mn)$, but twice in $\varphi(m)\varphi(n)$, so it is not necessary that one factor is prime to conclude the coprimality from $\varphi(mn) = \varphi(m)\varphi(n)$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why $\phi(ap)=\phi(a)p$ If p divides a?

Comment: It's from the formula for the totient. Let $a = p^k\cdot b$ with $p \nmid b$. Then $\varphi(a) = \varphi(p^k)\varphi(b) = (p-1)p^{k-1}\varphi(b)$, and $\varphi(ap) = \varphi(p^{k+1}b) = \varphi(p^{k+1})\varphi(b) = (p-1)p^k\varphi(b)$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $a=p^sb$, with $p,b$ co-prime and $s>0$. Then: $$\phi(ap)=\phi(p^{s+1}b)=p^s(p-1)\phi(b)$$
and: $$\phi(a)\phi(p)=p^{s-1}(p-1)\phi(b)(p-1).$$
If $\phi(ap)=\phi(a)\phi(p)$, then $p=p-1$, a contradiction.

Comment: please format your code using latex. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference